# How to Create Video Editor & Maker - InShot type of Video Editing TimeLine Android Java

Tags: video, video-processing

I need This type of video editing timeline and real-time render preview.

[image]

Comment: critical skill to becoming a productive software engineer is to think about a question then zero into a set of underlying challenges each of which can be solved before stitching together those smaller easier simpler solutions ... I suggest you apply that here to think about your end goal then solve these underlying steps .. besides we are not your mother and do not give advice and as always post the code you have written in any question ... its far better to write some code and play about trying various approaches than to do nothing often this triggers surprising insights by just messing about

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're serious about making a video editor you need to respond and tell us where you are stuck. You showed a picture and we don't know what it means exactly. Are you asking how to add text, how to make a background black, how to capture frames as bitmaps? how to draw shapes (boxes)... It;s not obvious. You might even be asking how to ratio the length of timeline against the video length... but maybe you didn't ask that. I don't think there is an answer for your picture question.

Comment: You need to ask about **a real problem in your code** (like maybe you can't draw a box  correctly or you already got box but can't ratio its length against video length????).

Comment: VC.One thank you for your reply. I need multiple timelines or track lines. link inshort video track line or other video editing application. the making length of timeline against the video. example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camerasideas.instashot